# Get G Suite seat pricing (especially with discounts)

Tags: google-reseller-api

Using the [Google Reseller API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/get-start/getting-started) I am making a tool to order new licenses (increase seats) for G Suite users.

Now I have the current prices in my database, which works fine, but it doesn't account for specials, such as the upgrade from **G Suite Basic** to **G Suite Business** where the pricing 18 months for the price of 12 in the first contract period.

Is there a way to get the current pricing or specials for a G Suite seat?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same, so we can pipe the payments through our accounting software

Comment: @MrPablo No, there doesn't really seem a way for it other than creating the current discounts and calculating them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this blog: [HOW DO I ADD MORE LICENSES OR SEATS IN G SUITE?](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/googleapps/204645560/how-do-i-add-more-licenses-or-seats-in-g-suite) which discussed how to add seats to your G Suite for Work service.

> Be aware that the number of users you can create is limited to the number of user licenses or "seats" you have purchased. If you have reached your limit and need additional users you may always purchase more in the Account Center.

Also based from this [page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247360?hl=en), if your team grows, you can purchase [more licenses](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33387) and your monthly rate goes up.  You may learn more on how to manage user licenses for either plan type in this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1727173).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, it's not the ordering that is the problem. I am connecting to the Google Reseller API to order new seats, and this works without problems. But I am looking for an option to request the price per seat (or discounts) for a certain customer during this ordering process.